# Get an image asynchronously performs an error

Tags: android, asynchronous, xamarin, android-adapter, android-bitmap

In `Xamarin`, I have a `GridView` adapter that sets images for each `GridView` item. This `GridView` adapter is loaded from a `Fragment` as part of a `ViewPager`.

Each `GridView` item has an `ImageView` that displays an image. I have some code that displays the image correctly when downloading an image synchronously, however, not asynchronously.

Here is my code:

```
public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null)
        view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.GridViewWithImageAndTextItem, gridView, false);
    imgIcon =  view.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.image);
    if (gridViewtems[position].useResourceAsThumbnail) 
    {
        imgIcon.SetImageResource (gridViewtems[position].imageResourceId);
    } else {
        //Code that does work
        imgIcon.SetImageBitmap (GetImageBitmapFromUrl (gridViewtems[position].thumbNailWebAddress));
        //Code that does not work
        DownloadAsyncBitmap (gridViewtems[position].thumbNailWebAddress, imgIcon);
    }
    view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.myImageViewText).Text = gridViewtems[position].text;
    return view;
}

async void DownloadAsyncBitmap(string url, ImageView imageView)
{
    var webClient = new WebClient ();
    var uri = new Uri (url);
    byte[] bytes = null;
    try
    {
        bytes = await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(uri);
    }
    catch(TaskCanceledException){
        Console.WriteLine ("Task Canceled!");
        return;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Console.WriteLine (e.ToString());
        return;
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = await BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArrayAsync (bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    imageView.SetImageBitmap (bitmap);
}

private Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
{
    Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
        if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
        {
            imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        }
    }

    return imageBitmap;
}
```

This is the application output when trying to use the asynchronous code:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsableAttribute' not found.
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerAdaptor.BuildAttribute[T](CustomAttributeDataMirror attr)
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerAdaptor.GetAttribute[T](CustomAttributeDataMirror[] attrs)
   at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerAdaptor.OnGetTypeDisplayData(EvaluationContext ctx, Object type)
```

This exact code works in another application of mine, but not in this application with Google Maps. Is there some permission that I am missing?

May I please have some help to set the images asynchronously?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Thank you for the resource, I have read it and now understand more about async and await operators.

Here is my current code:

```
async Task<Bitmap> DownloadBitmapAsync(string url)
{
    var webClient = new HttpClient ();
    var uri = new Uri (url);
    byte[] bytes = null;

    try
    {
        bytes = await webClient.GetByteArrayAsync(uri);
    }
    catch(TaskCanceledException){
        Console.WriteLine ("Task Canceled!");
        return null;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Console.WriteLine (e.ToString());
        return null;
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = await BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArrayAsync (bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return (bitmap);
}
```

And I am calling this code and setting the `Bitmap` with this code:

```
DownloadBitmapAsync(gridViewItems[position].thumbnailImageWebAddress)
    .ContinueWith(continuation => { imgIcon.SetImageBitmap (continuation.Result); });
```

The `GridView` displays, yet none of the `ImageView` objects have any images in them.

Is my code correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using async-await in the wrong way.

First of all, you should never return "void" from Async task.
So, your DownloadAsyncBitmap (proper name convention is DownloadBitmapAsync) must return Task (equivalent of void), or better yet, `Task<Bitmap>`.

Second, you call your task in the wrong way. There are approach named "async all the way", it means that you should return Task all way up to top-level interface method (command, clickEvent or getView). If this event returning `void` it is pretty simple to run Task asynchronously:

```
public async override void OnStart()
{
    await DoSomethingAsync();
}
```

You should understand, that async-wait is just syntax sugar around Tasks and continuations.
So, if your method can't return `void` (like your GetView) you can use ContinueWith construction.

In your case the proper way to start async task from GetView is:

```
DownloadAsyncBitmap(gridViewtems[position].thumbNailWebAddress)
    .ContinueWith(continuation => { imageView.SetImageBitmap (continuation.Result); });
```

I recommend you to study async-await a little more http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

ImageView is a view and should only be manipulated on the UI thread. Not sure if this solves your problem:

```
((Activity)Context).RunOnUiThread (() => {imageView.SetImageBitmap (bitmap);} );
```